# Constraints for Recursive Types

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, recursive-type

I have a type `data A a = B (a (A a))`. How can I put a constraint on the type var `a` in function `something :: Eq (a b) => A a -> SomeType`?

Comment: Presumably you actually use `Eq (a (A a))` (not `Eq (a b)` for some arbitrary `b`) in the implementation of `something`, no?

Answer (score 6):

It's not completely clear to me what you want to achieve, but this compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}

data A a = B (a (A a))

deriving instance (forall t. Eq t => Eq (a t)) => Eq (A a)

something :: (forall t. Eq t => Eq (a t)) => A a -> String
something x 
   | x==x      = "hello"
   | otherwise = "world"
```

The trick here is to require that `Eq (a t)` holds for any possible `t`. That requires `QuantifiedConstraints`.

Of course, you can also use a more modest approach and require instead

```
something :: Eq (a Bool) => A a -> String
```

but that won't allow you to use `==` on the argument.

Alternatively,

```
something :: Eq (A a) => A a -> String
```

should work, even if it triggers a warning.

Comment: I have not seen QuantifiedConstraints before, so thanks. That works for me

Comment: @WilliamRusnack It was only introduced about a year ago, in GHC 8.6.1.